# Cannot connect to eks cluster via kubectl

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am finding it impossible to connect to my k8s cluster on eks.

I am getting the error

```
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

However,

I have multiple clusters:

```sh
$ kubectl config get-clusters
NAME
hilarious-unicorn-1568659474.eu-west-1.eksctl.io
arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:<redacted>:cluster/derp
```

These *also* appear when I do

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts
```

My issue is, if I switch to my eu-west cluster/context by running `kubectl config use-context <my context>`

And then do `kubectl cluster-info` I get

```
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

I have ran

```
$ aws eks update-kubeconfig --name myCluster
```

And this has updated in my `~/.kube/config` file but to no avail.

I am literally at a loss as to why this is not working because it was previously working, and I can authenticate on another cluster.

## Edits due to Comments

1. @Eduardo Baitello

   - I have `aws-iam-authenticator` installed. Although we also use [awsmfa](https://pypi.org/project/awsmfa/0.2.3/).

Here is the contents of my `.kube/config`

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: redacted
    server: redacted
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:redacted:cluster/savvy
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: redacted
    server: redacted
  name: hilarious-unicorn-1568659474.eu-west-1.eksctl.io
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:redacted:cluster/savvy
    user: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:redacted:cluster/savvy
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:redacted:cluster/savvy
- context:
    cluster: hilarious-unicorn-1568659474.eu-west-1.eksctl.io
    user: karl@hilarious-unicorn-1568659474.eu-west-1.eksctl.io
  name: karl@hilarious-unicorn-1568659474.eu-west-1.eksctl.io
current-context: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:redacted:cluster/savvy
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:redacted:cluster/savvy
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - eu-west-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - savvy
      command: aws
- name: karl@hilarious-unicorn-1568659474.eu-west-1.eksctl.io
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - hilarious-unicorn-1568659474
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env: null
```

2. @shogan

Running `kubectl describe configmap -n kube-system aws-auth` says I am `(Unauthorized)`

Comment: Hi Karl. Are you following the [official guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-auth.html) to configure the cluster authentication? Can you post how your kubeconfig file is (remember to redact sensitive info). Also, make sure that you have the [aws-iam-authenticator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html) installed,

Comment: Also make sure your IAM user account that you are using (the context under which you are running `kubectl` and `aws-iam-authenticator`) is authorized in the cluster. There is a ConfigMap that can be used to map AWS IAM user accounts to Kubernetes privileges in the cluster called **aws-auth**.

If you can get someone else to describe it for you, you can check if your account is still mapped. `kubectl describe configmap -n kube-system aws-auth`. More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html

Comment: Hey guys, please see my updated question. I believe this might be my issue? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/amazon-eks-cluster-access/

Comment: did you try those solutions provided in `awsmfa documentaion` [Getting Started](https://pypi.org/project/awsmfa/), 
[AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_configure-api-require.html#MFAProtectedAPI-user-mfa)
[starter kit of basic IAM policies included with awsmfa](https://github.com/dcoker/awsmfa/blob/master/awsmfa/awsmfa-basic-policies.json)